# How to disable react native confirm navigation pop-up

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, webview, react-native-community

its showing when login or logout[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1rw4.jpg)
and also its auto disabled when i update into new build .but also happening after uninstall and install

How can i remove or disable the popup from my app .please help to solve this issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.